# Accidently Deleted Partition How to Recover Windows?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows, data-recovery

I accidently delelted the partition lists (I did not write anything to the drive, just a simple delete using gparted.

I initially had partitions like so (if I remember correctly)

- 500 MB EFS
- 128 MB Windows Reserved Partition
- 178 GB Windows File System
- 270 GB empty space..
- some other stuff??

I ran gpart, and it can find most of these partitions, but not the windows 128 MB reserved one. I tried to recreate the log using testdisk

But I cannot reboot into windows 10, I tried solutions listed [here](http://windowsreport.com/drive-windows-installed-locked/) and none of them worked...

Is there a way to fix this through ubuntu live boot?

Comment: No, there isn't. If you need to recover Windows you need Windows media.

Comment: @MichaelBay I have windows media, how can I proceed? I keep getting errors like "disk is locked.. "

Comment: You may ask at [super.se]. Installing Windows is off topic here ;)

Comment: Just follow the instructions in above answer.  Your problem might be different, but the answer is exactly your use-case...